# Зумирование нарисованных (graphics.h) объектов

Tags: c++, graphics, zoom

Есть ли способ зумировать нарисованные с помощью ***graphics.h*** объекты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о том graphics.h, который в Turbo C++ 3.0 восемьдесят дцатого года издания, то нет, такого способа нет. Потому как это примитивный растеризатор.

Comment: А что есть кроме graphics.h ?

Comment: @ARTAGE либо написать свою надстройку над ним, либо переместиться на 36 лет вперед и начать программировать под современные графические фреймворки. Qt, OpenGL и так далее.

Comment: Есть ли уроки (книги) по созданию надстройки или собственного вело... фреймворка?

Comment: @ARTAGE https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34114355/

https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/107800/